# Logstash Python API to read from files

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, elasticsearch, logstash

My requirement is to read from Logstash based log files, and index them into Elasticsearch.

For now, I have configured the Logstash and started the daemon to do so.

But what I need to know is if there is any existing Python2.x API for Logstash for the mentioned use-case.

Comment: What does "Logstash based log file" mean? If you want to index logs with Elasticsearch, Logstash itself would be highly useful. What is it that you want the Python script to do?

Comment: @Magnus By "Logstash based log file" I meant the log files that have already been written using log files.
Such is my use-case, that I need to use a python script to push the files to elasticsearch.
If you have any other way out using Python - that would be highly useful.

Comment: If you have on-disk logfiles that you want to push to Elasticsearch, Logstash would be an obvious candidate. It's not clear why you would have to write a custom Python script.

Comment: @Magnus because as per my use-case I will get list of files that need to be pushed to ES, and this may vary all the time. Thus, I need this to be done through python. How else would you suggest ?

Comment: > log files that have already been written using log files....   So, how do you write files with themselves?

Answer (score 0):

As the question have been about "how can I push a specific file to the elasticsearch via logstash with python", I'd suggest to:

1. Observe a directory for *.log with filebeat or logstash directly.
2. Create symlinks for files you need to push.